# How to write pre processed image

Tags: image, directory, output, kaggle

#Read the image

```
img = cv2.imread('../input/jagan-ap/AP CM Jagan Mohan Reddy approves....jpg')
```

#Pre processed the image. (Done pre-processing)

#Then I want to write this image into output directory of the Kaggle, tried below options but no use:

```
1    img.fromarray(roi_color).save('./output/')

2    cv2.imwrite('./output/',img)

3    plt.imsave(img, 'saveName.jpg')
```

Kindly suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you used **OpenCV** to open the image and you already have that as a dependency, there's little reason to suddenly introduce **PIL** or **matplotlib** as further deoendencies as in 1) and 3). Furthermore, your colours will be wrong because **OpenCV** uses BGR ordering and the others use RGB.

So, let's look at 2). If `output` is a directory, that can't work. You need to write to a file, so try:

```
cv2.imwrite('output/result.png',img)
```